# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main' - GCP App Engine

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting this error when trying to deploy my Flask API to GCP App Engine:

```
    2023-05-16 07:49:30 default[20230516t084639]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process      super().init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
       File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app      mod = importlib.import_module(module)    File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

This is my app.yaml file in my root directory:

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app


instance_class: F1

automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 10
```

This is my main.py file also in my root directory:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, send_file, current_app, Flask
from app.services.commitgraph import (
    fetch_commit_count_per_day,
    plot_commit_count,
    RepoNotFoundError,
    NoCommitsFoundError,
    InvalidUsername,
    THEMES,
    TYPES,
)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/v1/commit-graph", methods=["GET"])
def get_commit_graph():

    ***Code omitted for brevity.***


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.0.7
cycler==0.11.0
Flask==2.3.2
fonttools==4.39.4
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.6.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.7.1
numpy==1.24.3
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.0.1
Pillow==9.5.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
requests==2.30.0
scipy==1.10.1
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.2
Werkzeug==2.3.4
zipp==3.15.0
```

Project file structure:

```
 project_root/
    main.py
    app.yaml
    requirements.txt
    app/
        __init__.py
        api/
            __init__.py

    services/
        commitgraph.py
```

Please let me know if there is any further detail needed and I will be happy to post. Appreciate all of the help in advance!

Comment: What's your project (file and folder) structure?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere edited the initial question, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by erasing my GCP project and creating a new one from scratch, not sure why it fixed my issue. Perhaps there was something cached in my previous config when deploying my app.